# devexpress xtrab control(windows form). align tab vertically

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I am creating a Windows form application. I am using Devexpress 11.1.

Is it possible to **align Tabs** of a xtrab control **vertically** instead of horizontally.

If so, please help me out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to look at 2 properties on xtraTabControl:

`HeaderOrientation` and `HeaderLocation`

Orientation will allow you to set it to vertical and Location for which side.

```
 XtraTabControl1.HeaderLocation = DevExpress.XtraTab.TabHeaderLocation.Left;
 XtraTabControl1.HeaderOrientation = DevExpress.XtraTab.TabOrientation.Vertical;
```